# Splitting consecutive similar characters of a specific length in an array of strings

Tags: python

I have an array

```
["ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehh"]
```

and need to extract consecutive characters in each string element of length `k` (in this case 3) without using regex or groupby.

This is what I have so far:

```
s = ["ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehhh"]
k = 3
output = []
for i in s:
    result = ""
    for j in range(1,len(i)-1):
        if i[j]==i[j-1] or i[j]==i[j+1]:
            result+=i[j]
    if i[-1] == result[-1]:
        result+=i[-1]
    if i[0]==result[0]:
        result=i[0]+result
    output.append(result)
print(output)

#current output = ['jjjjmmtthh', 'xxuuee', 'aallrrrxx', 'qqqaaabbb', 'oocccffuucccjjjkkkyyyeehhh'] 
#expected outcome(for k =3) = ['rrr','qqq','aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','jjj','kkk','yyy','hhh']
```

My questions:

1. How can I accommodate the `k` condition?
2. Is there a more optimal way to do this?

Comment: Given your sample inputs, what's expected outputs?  Examples are helpful.

Comment: @DanielHao Thank you for the tip. I've edited the original post. Expected outcome for k=3 should be ['rrr','qqq','aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','jjj','kkk','yyy','hhh']. All my code gets so far is ['jjjjmmtthh', 'xxuuee', 'aallrrrxx', 'qqqaaabbb', 'oocccffuucccjjjkkkyyyeehhh']

Comment: The question does not specifiy the intended functionality in sufficient detail: if a letter occurs more than k times, what is supposed to happen? (ignore that occurence?) What if it occurs 2*k times? Return twice or not at all?

Comment: @guidot I'd say the jjjj in their example makes that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is more readable and not too long. It works for k > 0.

```
s = ["ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehhh"]
k = 3
output = []
for element in s:
    state = "" #State variable (reset on every list item)
    for char in element: #For each character
        if state != "" and char == state[-1]:  # Check if the last character is the same (only if state isn't empty)
            state += char #Add it to the state
        else:
            if len(state) == k: #Otherwise, check if we have k characters
                output.append(state) #Append te result if we do
            state = char #Reset the state
    #If there are no more characters (end of element), check too
    if len(state) == k: 
        output.append(state)
print(output)
```

Output for `k = 3`

```
['rrr', 'qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']
```

Output for `k = 1`

```
['e', 'z', 'g', 'n', 'j', 'd', 'j']
```

Comment: With k=1, this produces `[' ', 'e', ' ', 'z', 'g', ' ', 'n', 'j', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'j']` (ok maybe they don't use k=1, but I wouldn't rule it out...)

Comment: @KellyBundy k=1 shouldn't be factored in  (I think?) because we're looking for consecutive. Or would you say the code should accommodate a possible exception?

Comment: @exysayOdercayUckday That's why I said maybe you don't use k=1. But to me, k=1 is just as valid as k>1, that's why I said I wouldn't rule it out. At least not without saying so. Someone might use this thinking it works for k=1 because they didn't say it doesn't, and then get into trouble. Note that Python's itertools.groupby also doesn't discard "groups" of size 1, which is just as much an "exception" (I don't consider it an exception in either case). Not sure what to think about k=0 here. I think there's no clear expectation about that, so I wouldn't mind much if that silently "doesn't work".

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right. When k = 1, because it didn't check if `state` was a space, the algorithm appended it anyway. I used a space instead of an empty string in order to save the extra condition that would check if the string was empty to avoid `string index out of range` when slicing it. I've corrected it by changing `state`'s initial value to empty and adding the extra condition. Thank you for pointing out the error! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I group the letters manually by consecutive same letters. Then I only count them to the result in case they have the same length as k. This works but I am sure there is a more optimal way:

```
s = ["ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehhh"]
k = 3

def _next_group(st):
    if not st:
        return None
    first = st[0]
    res = [first]
    for s in st[1:]:
        if s == first:
            res.append(s)
        else:
            break
    return res

result = []
for st in s:
    while True:
        group = _next_group(st)
        if not group:
            break
        if len(group) == k:
            result.append("".join(group))
        if len(group) == len(st):
            break
        st = st[len(group):]

print(result)
```

Output:
`['rrr', 'qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']`

Answer (score 0):

A `for`-loop approach.

Remark: I suggest a **divide-and-conquer** solution: focus on a *single* string (and not on a list of strings) and make a function that works and then *generalize* it with loops/comprehension...

```
def repeated_chars(string, k=3):
    out = []
    c, tmp = 0, '' # counter, tmp char
    for char in s:
        if tmp == '':
            tmp = char
            c += 1
            continue

        if tmp == char:
            c += 1
        else:
            if c == k:
                out.append((tmp, c))
            tmp = char
            c = 1

    # last term
    if c == k:
        out.append((tmp, c))

    return [char * i for char, i in out]

data = ['jjjjmmtthh', 'xxuuee', 'aallrrrxx', 'qqqaaabbb', 'oocccffuucccjjjkkkyyyeehhh']

# apply the function to all strings
out = []
for s in data:
    out.extend(repeated_chars(s, k=3))

print(out)
#['rrr', 'qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Yes, `groubpy` shouldn't be used as per requirement, but doing the job requires to groupby in some way (see accepted answer for example), so it seems a good idea to split the responsibilities into multiple functions, as is good practice, by reimplementing a `groupby`.

`groupby` seems obvious in that case, if you can't use the one from `itertools`, just write one.

Also the core function should work on a string, not a list of strings -- just for loop in case you have a list of strings.

Once you have your `groubpy` it is straightforward:

```py
def extract_groups(s: str, k: int):
    return [group for group in groupby(s) if len(group) == k]
```

Let's try it out:

```py
input_strings = [
    "ejjjjmmtthh",
    "zxxuueeg",
    "aanlljrrrxx",
    "dqqqaaabbb",
    "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehhh",
]

expected_outputs = [
    [],
    [],
    ["rrr"],
    ["qqq", "aaa", "bbb"],
    ["ccc", "ccc", "jjj", "kkk", "yyy", "hhh"],
]

outputs = [extract_groups(s, k=3) for s in input_strings]

print(outputs == expected_outputs)  # True
```

As it is `outputs` is a list of groups:

```py
In [  ]: outputs
Out[  ]: [[], [], ['rrr'], ['qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']]
```

If you really want it flat, flatten it:

```py
In [  ]: from itertools import chain
   ... : list(chain.from_iterable(outputs))
Out[  ]: ['rrr', 'qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']

In [  ]: [group for s in input_strings for group in extract_groups(s, k)]
Out[  ]: ['rrr', 'qqq', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'yyy', 'hhh']
```

The `groupby` function for reference:

```py
def groupby(s: str):
    if not s:
        return []

    result = []
    tgt = s[0]
    counter = 1

    for c in s[1:]:
        if c == tgt:
            counter += 1
        else:
            result.append(tgt * counter)
            tgt = c
            counter = 1
    result.append(tgt * counter)

    return result
```

Comment: Same issue as deleted answer: groupby was excluded by the question. ANd I don't believe it is due to the implemenation provided by standard library.

Comment: Yes and I suggest to reimplement it, it seems the cleanest to me.

Comment: It makes no sense, doing the job requires to groupby, so why not splitting jobs in multiple functions, as is good practice.